# Triptych of Animal Cryptics

Tags: crosswords, cryptic-crosswords, animals

Here is a triptych of miniature cryptics for the animal lover in you.

---

## 1.

[image]

**Across**

3. Slowpoke slain gruesomely (5)
4. Humpback turned up fourth of whales (5)

**Down**

1. Gang of weasels tiptoe (5)
2. Very important person arrives at emergency room in sports car (5)

---

## 2.

[image]

**Across**

3. Hustler lays low in Wabash, Arkansas (5)
4. Madagascan mammal is wayward mule, right? (5)

**Down**

1. Fresh re-write needs this unpleasant, ill-tempered archetype (5)
2. Freshwater fish mangled tutor (5)

---

## 3.

[image]

**Across**

3. Gang of Irwin intimates stay on top (5)
4. South gets cold for jay crew (5)

**Down**

1. Film a bunch of bunnies (5)
2. Large bird of prey decapitated hound (5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grid 1:

> SNAIL* ; CAME + _L_ ; SNEAK (ddef) ; V.I.P. + ER *(thanks, Rubio!)*
>
> `#S#V#`
> `SNAIL`
> `#E#P#`
> `CAMEL`
> `#K#R#`

Grid 2:

> _SH ARK_ ; (LEMU*)R ; _SH RE-W_ ; TROUT*
>
> ```
> #S#T#
> SHARK
> #R#O#
> LEMUR
> #W#T#
> ```

Grid 3:

> FLOAT (ddef) ; S+COLD (?) ; FLICK (ddef) ; (-b)EAGLE
>
> ```
> #F#E#
> FLOAT
> #I#G#
> SCOLD
> #K#E#
> ```

Comment: you're too quick!

Answer (score 4):

#### Partial Answer

**1**

> ```
>   S   V
> S N A I L
>   E   P
> C A M E L
>   K   R
> ```

Comment: @deusovi is entirely too fast at these.  :)  I humbly submit!